# H10 Error in Flask App when deployed on heroku

Tags: python, flask, heroku

My app is working perfectly on local host but I am getting the following error when I deployed my flask app on heroku

```
2020-07-01T09:56:02.982007+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=webscrappingapp.herokuapp.com request_id=59cec0a7-98a3-49d8-b980-779cada2c0d9 fwd="103.40.197.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-07-01T09:56:03.765421+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=webscrappingapp.herokuapp.com request_id=b2ddd2b8-5930-4049-993d-3c8e972b10ee fwd="103.40.197.230" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Flask file,
webscrap.py--

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone

#__name__ == __main__
app = Flask(__name__)
URL = 'https://techcrunch.com/'
page = requests.get(URL)  # type of page -- request

# type coverted to BeautifulSoup
# second argument how you want to structure your data
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

results = soup.find(class_='river river--homepage')

post_elems = results.select('.post-block')

table = [['Sr No', 'Time Stamp', 'News Title', 'Image Source URL', 'Author']]
i = 1

for post_elem in post_elems:
    header_elem = post_elem.find('header', class_='post-block__header')
    title_elem = header_elem.find('a', class_='post-block__title__link')
    timeStamp_elem = header_elem.find('time')['datetime']
    author_elem = header_elem.find('span')
    image_elem = post_elem.find('img')
    date = datetime.strptime(timeStamp_elem, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z" )
    row = [i,  date.astimezone(timezone('Asia/Kolkata')).strftime("%I:%M %p" + " IST " + "%B %d, %Y"), title_elem.text.strip(),
           image_elem.get('src'), author_elem.text.strip()]
    table.append(row)
    i = i + 1

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", table=table)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Procfile:

```
web : gunicorn webscrap:app
```

Requirements.txt:

```
autopep8==1.5.3
beautifulsoup4==4.9.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.1
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
idna==2.10
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
pycodestyle==2.6.0
pytz==2020.1
requests==2.24.0
soupsieve==2.0.1
toml==0.10.1
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

I tried replacing the Procfile content with

```
web : gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:$PORT webscrap:app
```

But it didn't worked for me. I also tried replacing `app` with `server` but didn't worked. So, please suggest the solution for this problem.

EDIT:
My mistake was spacing in Procfile. Correct one is --

```
web: gunicorn webscrap:app
```

But now I am getting H14 error also tried adding `heroku ps:scale web=1` in Procfile but didn't worked for me.

Comment: I'm not sure if this gets executed with `gunicorn` but on Heroku you cannot run Flask in debug mode. `app.run(debug=True)`. Should be  `False` or omitted. You can also specify a port there `app.run(port=os.environ.get("PORT", 8080))` (will bind to `PORT` if exists, else use port 8080) Also try running your Flask app without gunicorn and hope for some more meaningfull error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change Procfile txt to

```
web: uwsgi uwsgi.ini
```

create new file uwsgi.ini and add this code

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :$(PORT)
master = true
die-on-term = true
module = app:app
memory-report = true
```

Add uwsgi in requirement.txt

```
...
urllib3==1.25.9
Werkzeug==1.0.1
uwsgi
```

Add runtime.txt and add this text

```
python-version
```

for example python-3.7.4

Comment: NO, I don't have runtime.txt file

Comment: Do I need to include .flaskenv file also?

Comment: No there is no need of adding .env file. how you deploy app to heroku

Comment: okay, ```git add .```  --> ```git commit -m "message" ``` --> ```heroku create webscrappingapp``` --> ```git push heroku master```

Comment: also i came across this solution ```port = int(os.environ.get("PORT", 5000))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)```, Is this helpful?

Comment: is your project on Github, if on GitHub then I can check it my self if you want

Comment: you can also see my project that i deploy on heroku https://github.com/2016CS107/fyp-project/tree/master/Backend%20API

Comment: you can see this that i deploy on heroku https://testwebscrap.herokuapp.com/, the changes made in this repository https://github.com/2016CS107/webscrap

Comment: I forgot to add runtime.txt but it still worked (finally!) Still wondering what is that file for?

Answer (score 0):

My Project Structure

[image: My Project Structure]
Create Procfile - write a following line into it
`web: gunicorn main:app`
where "main" is the file name in which **app = create_app()** is mentioned

`pip install gunicorn`

`pip freeze > requirements.txt`

create one more file named `runtime.txt` which contains following line
`python-3.9.2`
(provide respective python version of your project)

> Heroku Part: run following commands one by one using gitbash or vscode console

`heroku login`

`git init`

`git add .`

`git commit -am "Initial Commit"`

`git push heroku main`

Answer (score 0):

first of all: the word "Procfile" should be started with capital letter
then keep the procfile in the same directory of the app folder.

secondly, try the following code in Procfile
`web: gunicorn app:app --preload`
and don't forget to save changes made in the Procfile

finally, go to the terminal and apply `git push heroku master`

hope this help you

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).