# H10 error in heroku after deploying the python app

Tags: python, heroku, beautifulsoup

[image]I have scrape website data using python BeautifulSoup. And after successfully deploying it on heroku it gives me the H10 error which is app creashed.
I did not understand this error.

My Procfile has...
web: run this thing

I cannot understand the cause of error that where this error occurs.

Comment: Can you please share the contents of the Procfile.

Comment: My contents of procfile is only "web: run this thing".Nothing anything else.

Answer (score 0):

The H10 Heroku error is fairly vague, it is just thrown when an app crashes. However, some reasons for an H10 error include:

1. Procfile bug
2. Missing necessary environment variables
3. PORT as Heroku environment variable

H10 is usually thrown in Python when there is an error in your Procfile, so perhaps look into that. I suggest installing [gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) which is a WSGI HTTP server.

Some inspiration for the Procfile is linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62676262/h10-error-in-flask-app-when-deployed-on-heroku)